# Display flex with mixed design

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

What would be the best way to make the following with flexbox? I would like 2 rows that are equal width columns, however, the last column to be 100% height and fill the rest of the section.

Would it be best to use multiple rows for this?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.col {display:1;width:30%;background:red;}

.col:nth-of-type(3) {background:blue;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  test
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  test
  </div>
   <div class="col">
  test
  </div>
   <div class="col">
  test
  </div>
   <div class="col">
  test
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`CSS grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

1. Define the `row` as *grid container* using `display: grid`.
2. Define the *3-column layout* by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)`
3. Define the *2-column layout* by using `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)`
4. *Span* the *third column* to *all* the rows by using `grid-row: span 2`.
5. Adjust the *gaps* between the rows & columns using `grid-gap` property.

See demo below:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 equal columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr); /* 2 equal rows */
  grid-gap: 10px; /* gap between the rows & columns */
}
.col {
  background: red;
}
.col:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: blue;
  grid-row: span 2; /* span all the rows */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test</div>
  <div class="col">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way you can target the first and fourth column to make this 50% width?

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 50% repeat(2, 1fr)` should do fine I guess (without adjusting for the `grid-gap` of course)... `grid-template-columns: calc(50% - 10px) repeat(2, 1fr)` adjusting for the `grid-gap`...

Comment: Sorry Kukkuz I meant to target the 2nd and 5th. Like this:- http://www.project-progress.co.uk/aa.png

Comment: you can use `grid-template-columns:  1fr calc(50% - 10px)  1fr`

Comment: Thats brilliant thank you! I am just trying to workout how to use multiple designs with Flexbox. Thank you